# convert the date column of the dataframe to the date type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd
      from datetime import datetime

      df = pd.DataFrame({'Id_sensor': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                         'Date_start': ['2018-01-04 00:00:00.0', '2018-01-04 00:00:10.0',
                                        '2018-01-04 00:14:00.0', '2018-01-04'],
                         'Date_end': ['2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2017-01-06', '2018-01-05']})
```

The columns (Date_start and Date_end) are of type Object. I would like to transform to the data type of dates. And make the columns look the same. That is, in other words, fill in the date, hour and minute fields with zeros that the column (Date_end) does not have.

I tried to make the following code:

```
      df['Date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
      df['Date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

My output:

```
        Id_sensor     Date_start         Date_end
           1       2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-05
           2       2018-01-04 00:00:10  2018-01-06
           3       2018-01-04 00:14:00  2017-01-06
           4       2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-05
```

But I would like the output to be like this:

```
           Id_sensor      Date_start         Date_end
           1       2018-01-04 00:00:00    2018-01-05 00:00:00
           2       2018-01-04 00:00:10    2018-01-06 00:00:00
           3       2018-01-04 00:14:00    2017-01-06 00:00:00
           4       2018-01-04 00:00:00    2018-01-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: It's just `df['Date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start'])`. The format is not how you want your output, its the format of your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening is that both Series `df['Date_start']` and `df['Date_end']` are of type *datetime64[ns]*, but when you show the dataframe, if all the time values of the columns are zero, it doesn't show them. What you can try, if you need a formatted output, is to convert them to object types again, and give them format with [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['Date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Id_sensor           Date_start             Date_end
0          1  2018/01/04 00:00:00  2018/01/05 00:00:00
1          2  2018/01/04 00:00:10  2018/01/06 00:00:00
2          3  2018/01/04 00:14:00  2017/01/06 00:00:00
3          4  2018/01/04 00:00:00  2018/01/05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your columns to `datetime` datatype using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), and subsequently use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert the columns to string datatype with your desired format:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id_sensor': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'Date_start': ['2018-01-04 00:00:00.0', '2018-01-04 00:00:10.0',
                   '2018-01-04 00:14:00.0', '2018-01-04'],
    'Date_end': ['2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2017-01-06', '2018-01-05']})

df['Date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['Date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df)
# Output:
#
#    Id_sensor           Date_start             Date_end
# 0          1  2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-05 00:00:00
# 1          2  2018-01-04 00:00:10  2018-01-06 00:00:00
# 2          3  2018-01-04 00:14:00  2017-01-06 00:00:00
# 3          4  2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-05 00:00:00
```